# Word 2016 inserted RevNum field will not auto-update

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office

I inserted the document revision from Insert->Quick Parts->Field->RevNum into my document.

It never updates the number unless I use F9 after highlighting it. This occurs for all fields including current Date+Time and last save time.

How do I set the fields to auto-update when I save the document so I can see what was saved? I found the option to update when opening, and the one for updating when printing. But how will I know which document revision to tell people about when I save when I then have to re-open it to get the revision?

Answer (score 1):

You can put this code into `ThisDocument` object in VBA.

```
Private WithEvents App As Word.Application

Private Sub Document_Open()
  Set App = Word.Application
End Sub

Private Sub App_DocumentBeforeSave(ByVal Doc As Document, SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
  ActiveDocument.Fields.Update
End Sub
```

OR - if you are using SaveAs command:

```
Sub FileSaveAs()

  Dialogs(wdDialogFileSaveAs).Show

  'returns the name including the .doc extension 
  ChosenFileNameAndExtension = ActiveDocument.Name 'Or use .FullName

  ActiveDocument.Fields.Update

End Sub
```